# Typescript types for chartjs-adapter-date-fns

Tags: typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs, date-fns

My code works but under my import statements I have 2 dots and if I hover over them it shows the error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns'. '/home/user/dev/website/client/node_modules/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/chartjs-adapter-date-fns` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';`ts(7016)
```

I tried `yarn add -D @types/chartjs-adapter-date-fns` but that seems not to exist. Is the problem that I am missing the typescript types? How can I get rid of this error?

---

My import statements just in case:

```
import {
  CategoryScale,
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Filler,
  Legend,
  LinearScale,
  LineElement,
  PointElement,
  TimeScale,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
} from 'chart.js'
import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns'
import { enGB } from 'date-fns/locale'
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2'
import { useMarketDataQuery } from '../generated/graphql'
import BaseCard from './BaseCard'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify your own type definitions for this package.

There are [three ways how the library can be typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html#external-definitions):

- Bundled Types
- DefinitelyTyped / @types
- Your Own Definitions

As the types aren't bundled with the `chartjs-adapter-date-fns` package and there are no `@types` for it in the `DefinitelyTyped` repository, the only option you have is to provide [your own type definition for this package](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html#your-own-definitions).

The easiest way to do it is to add an empty declaration for it in a .d.ts file in your project with the content.

```
declare module "chartjs-adapter-date-fns";
```

It will silence warnings about this module

Comment: Where would you put this file? should I make a folder src/types?

Comment: Yes, it might be a good option.

It's up to you where to put declaration files. It's important to make sure that these files are included in `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 1):

The date adapter does not export any functionalities so you can just add a `// @ts-ignore` above the import or create your own declaration file whith an empty module that provides the typing for the date adapter.

All the typings for the config itself are already provided by chart.js itself.

Comment: I tried the `// @ts-ignore` method but that didn't work - any idea why that could be?

Comment: No also cant seem to reproduce it, dont get any errors on it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQBYENZwL5wGZQQhwDkAxhrAHQBWAziQNwCwAUKJFuZTPQLToAJujAwAplD7DxfPADsGbNgDdMcMjAAecALxxBEMgFcQYuTCoBzMTACiAGzGnzAIQCeASUEAKAEQg3NEwYXwBKOHQ6OAAJABUAWQAZZHQ5VToHJzMYFlZVKDgAoKw9OTEAdxQebw1NABpENjhmuBg3MDEALlJ7YDKSOqaW6XRuhCGWlvt0ACMxezpugG1fACUxQV8G3xd7IzEtuF8ATXn7CHLD3wBxKDEzK4AFIygwRyuAeShU618AXUGrEmkxGdBsizgS3GQOBsOmc3s3RIAGI4BA8HAAGoQcQMQGw2EjZYARgATA1iQBOBoAZgaAFYGuS4DSARNgdg-uzsPiWhBRMAIAoxuzmnQyOhHBDoQS4JoRTDZW0OkiYKAxANRS0eVrmm4FbLmrqcFrsNy2NhQowgA

Comment: Could the issue with not being able to reproduce it be from my tsconfig? I have `{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },`

Comment: Don't know enough about that specifically to give you an answer about that